# How can I tell why my logs stopped saving into var/log/messages?

Tags: linux, logs

I'm new with Linux. I've only been backing up logs for a few weeks. This week, I went into the messages and found that they'd stopped being saved last week, roughly since the last time they'd been backed up. Typically, a new messages document is started at roughly the same time each week. As usual, a new document was automatically generated this week and logs began saving again. But I'm still missing the logs that stopped saving last week. Does anyone have any ideas on what happened here? Is there a way to recover those lost logs?

Answer (score 1):

A very strong possibility is that the /var/log/syslog file was renamed and deleted while open, and a new file of the same name created.

This results in messages being sent to the deleted file (in Unix you can do that as long as the file is kept open; the data will be written to disk, and be reflected in the available space decreasing).

Once the file is closed, then the file is truly deleted and all data is lost. You might, as a desperate last resort, dump the whole logical disk through the strings command as root, and grep for the log file lines in the deleted slack space. Assuming the filesystem is not compressed and there is no security provision to sanitize deleted files, in which cases you're up that infamous creek without a paddle.

```
# Assume log lines begin with YYYY-MM-DD and are from last week
# And assume that /var/log is on /dev/sda1.
# Save on a different disk or external USB device
dd if=/dev/sda1 | strings | grep "^2019-08-[23][0-9] ..:..:.. " > /mnt/usbkey/logs.txt
# After some hours, MAYBE you'll find something among all the rubbish in /mnt/usbkey/logs.txt
```

Or possibly the syslog daemon was stopped.

To check which files are open, locale syslog's pid, and look in /proc/PID_OF_SYSLOG/fd . You will see the file handles there; they're symbolic links to the actual open files.

If you see something like

3 -> /var/log/syslog    [deleted]

and there *is* a not-deleted /var/log/syslog, that means that *they are two different files*. Stopping and restarting syslog will fix that.

Some log-rotating scripts might at times, in their moving / renaming / compressing / deleting the old log files, do something silly like that.